# Some registry keys not return a value VB6

Tags: vb6, registry

I am trying to find out if the SQL Server 2012 Native client driver is installed.  I am told that checking this registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion
```

where inside a value name of VERSION will have a value meaning that it is installed.

When I call the API

```
If RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, KeyName, 0, KEY_READ, handle) Then
     Exit Function
End If
```

Where

```
    hkey=&H80000002
    KeyName=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion
```

it returns an error like it cannot find the key. I have tested with other keys and it opens them fine.  At first I thought it was because of the spaces in "Microsoft SQL Server", it is was not. I can see the key in the registry just fine.

Comment: What error code does RegOpenKeyEx return?

Answer (score 0):

In VB6, that number `&H80000002` comes out as `-2147483646`. Any non-zero value will be considered `True`, so you will always `Exit Function` as long as its a non-zero value. Its usually not a good idea to have this type of logic `If X Then ...`

suggestion:

```
If RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, KeyName, 0, KEY_READ, handle)=0 Then
     Exit Function
End If
```

EDIT: after re-reading your post, I am a bit confused at where the problem is. Is it a run-time error or simply the logic is not doing what its supposed to do?